# Create a touch slider JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, touch

I've been trying to make my slider touchable on mobile screen. When I grab the slider with the mouse (when I try it on pc) it works perfectly but it doesn't work on mobile screen (it's not touchable).

I've tried to call the "AddEventListener" with "touchstart", "touchend" and "touchmove". I'm not sure what I've been missing here. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
    <div class="inner-slider">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.card:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
}
.card:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
}
.slider-container {
    width: 80%;
    height: 350px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner-slider {
    width: 150%;
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
"use strict";


let sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.slider-container');
let innerSlider = document.querySelector('.inner-slider');

let pressed = false;
let startX;
let x;


// MOUSE

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
    pressed = true;
    startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
    sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
    pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
    if (!pressed) return;
    e.preventDefault();

    x = e.offsetX;

    innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
});



// MOBILE

sliderContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
    pressed = true;
    startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
    sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});
  
sliderContainer.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
    sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
    pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    if (!pressed) return;
    e.preventDefault();

    x = e.offsetX;

    innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
});
```

I know I could've reused functions in another EventListeners but I wanted to keet it more obvious.

```js
"use strict";


let sliderContainer = document.querySelector('.slider-container');
let innerSlider = document.querySelector('.inner-slider');

let pressed = false;
let startX;
let x;


// MOUSE

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
  startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
  pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!pressed) return;
  e.preventDefault();

  x = e.offsetX;

  innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
});



// MOBILE

sliderContainer.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
  pressed = true;
  startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener('touchend', () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
  pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  if (!pressed) return;
  e.preventDefault();

  x = e.offsetX;

  innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
});
```

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.card:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
}

.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-slider {
  width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container">
  <div class="inner-slider">
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't told us what exactly is not working

Comment: I explain a bit more to be more clear, thanks for letting me know.